# Average time between user sign up and first action in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench, aggregate-functions

I have been tasked to find the average time between user sign up and their first action on the app, i.e. joining a game.

We have an app that helps people find other basketball players.

I know that I have to use two tables
the first table being the users table and the second being the game_users

**Users Table**

```
id | first name | last name | email | created_at 
12| John |Smith | johnsmith@email.com| 2019-01-16 07:41:49
```

**Game users Table**

```
game_id | user_id | is_admin | active |created_at 
23 |        14 |     0      |   1      | 2020-04-18 09:42:34
```

active here refers to joining a game

How can I tell get the first time a user joined a game? and then compare that date with the sign up date from the users table?

my expect outcome would be something like this

```
game_id | user_id | Sign Up | game_user created at | time_between
23       | 12     |2019-01-16 07:41:49| 2019-01-18 09:42:34 | 2
```

Comment: Add the desired output with some detailed sample data.

Comment: *my expect outcome would be something like this* ??? Average - this is "over all" or "over a group", not for one separate user.

Comment: I don't need the average for one separate user, ill calculate the average after finding the difference for each user

Answer (score 0):

To get average time use:

```
SELECT AVG(TIMEDIFF(games.created_at, users.created_at))
FROM users
JOIN ( SELECT user_id, MIN(created_at) created_at
       FROM games
       GROUP BY user_id ) games ON users.id = games.user_id
```

To get the time for each separate user:

```
SELECT users.*, games.*, TIMEDIFF(games.created_at, users.created_at)
FROM users
JOIN ( SELECT user_id, MIN(created_at) created_at
       FROM games
       GROUP BY user_id ) games ON users.id = games.user_id
```